# GPS Coordinate - Data type in C++

Tags: c++, gps, coordinates, type-conversion

I am working on C++ with GPS coordinates, as the format is usually as following "338766,703"

I tested this data with some datatypes however after processing with vector, the output is just "338766" I couldn't keep the whole data of GPS point.

So I hope you can help me the appropriate solution of data type to store data of GPS points.

Comment: I tried double but after processing by the vector, with the longtitude and latitude, just the latitude works fine for double, the longtitude is still the same problem!

Comment: What does the file look like, what is its documented format and what locale are you using when parsing it?

Comment: original format : 338766,703|6196200,40088435 ( X , Y respectively) they are separated by the | symbol, I read them in a file and convert them into double by atof function, and after atof I get this result: (338668 / 6.19649e+06) I wish to have a full data as original one for the output! I am doing Convex Hull for a set of GPS coordinates, and the function will output a set of points of the Convex HUll Thanks

Comment: "," is not a decimal point, it seems to separate x and y, while "|" speoarates points. These Coordintaes are not in lat lon degrees, they are integer, find the spefification of that file format. further where geographically are these coordinates?

Comment: Yes, the | symbol separates two Lat and Long coordinates, this is an info which is received by the device including lat and long and other information. The "." has been replaced by me to "," (comma) in order to be processed by my function. So according to you, I should keep the "." ?

Answer (score 0):

it see that somewhere you, introduce a cast to integer. find and understand why. if you need to store the lat,lon as integer, multiply with 1e6 and cast to int.

Comment: As I read the coordinates in a file, I used atof to convert string to double. I print the result after atof and I had that out put (338668 / 6.19649e+06) . Thank you!